# Is it possible to import data from csv files into Teradata table?

Tags: python, teradata

Looking for importing data from csv/json files to Teradata, can we do it with Python code?

Comment: Loading *csv* is directly supported by all TD load utilities. regarding *JSON* there's support for `JSON` since TD15, 15.10 added `BSON/UBJSON`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Judging from some of the resources I found online it does see possible. Just use the csv and json libraries built into python to parse your input:

https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html and https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/json.html

Then use this python module I found under Teradata's site to insert your data via session.executes:
https://developer.teradata.com/tools/reference/teradata-python-module

Looking at some of their examples, this seems really similar to standard Database statements. You may also be able add data using pyodbc but I am unsure.
https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki

pyodbc can be installed via pip.